# Custom field in XML is not saving parametars in DB

Tags: xml, joomla, joomla3.0

This is code which creates custom field:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class JFormFieldCustom extends JFormField {

    protected $type = 'Custom';

    protected function getInput() {

        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query = 'SELECT id, title FROM #__content';
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

        $result = '';
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $result .= '<label>' . $row->title  . '</label><input type=checkbox name=article  value="' . $row->id .'"/>';
        }
        return $result;
    }

}
?>
```

And the code into XML file:

```
<field name="checkboxes" type="custom" default="" label="Articles" description="" />
```

The problem is that nothing is saved as params into DB. What is wrong here?

Comment: There isn't enough detail here to answer you question. e.g. is the "xml file" the general config file? Is it for a component, a module or what?

Comment: Sorry about that mate. I am trying to create module, and this XML file is general config file (it is in the root folder).

Comment: Why do you have a default? How are you expecting that to save given the nature of checkboxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems.

#### HTML & PHP Forms

If we unravel your for loop with some dummy data we get the following:

```html
<label>My Article Title 1</label><input type=checkbox name=article  value="1" />
<label>My Article Title 2</label><input type=checkbox name=article  value="2" />
<label>My Article Title 3</label><input type=checkbox name=article  value="3" />
<label>My Article Title 4</label><input type=checkbox name=article  value="4" />
```

So the most obvious problem is that you're passing the check boxes back as a single values (all with the same name) where your code indicates that you really want an array.

That HTML will render like this:

[image: Original Checkboxes]

and when submitted PHP will perceive it like this:

```php
var_dump($_POST);

array (size=1)
  'article' => string '3' (length=1)
```

So, to get an [array of a form element in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) you will need to append `[]` to the end of the name, i.e. `article[]`, to make the display vertical I've also added a `<br>` after each checkbox and properly quoted the attributes of the `<input>`. That gets us this:

```html
<label>My Article Title 1</label><input type="checkbox" name="articles[]"  value="1" /><br>
<label>My Article Title 2</label><input type="checkbox" name="articles[]"  value="2" /><br>
<label>My Article Title 3</label><input type="checkbox" name="articles[]"  value="3" /><br>
<label>My Article Title 4</label><input type="checkbox" name="articles[]"  value="4" /><br>
```

When this is submitted we can see PHP see's all the check options:

```php
var_dump($_POST);

array (size=1)
  'articles' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
```

#### Joomla Problems

1. You create a `JDatabaseQuery` object with the line `$query = $db->getQuery(true);`, but then immediately destroy it by overwriting in with a string of SQL.
2. Your table and column names are not appropriately quoted, quoting helps to prevent injection risks and reserved word conflicts. As quoting can vary by the underlying database, `JDatabase` provides a series of useful functions to make your SQL portable across the various DB's it supports so your query can be rewritten as:

```php
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array($db->quoteName('id'), $db->quoteName('title')));
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
```

3. I would recommend not using a generic type of 'Custom' (I realise that lots of tutorial use it but they are just examples), to avoid conflicts try something more descriptive like `ArticleCheckboxes`. So your PHP ends up more like this:

```php
class JFormFieldArticlesCheckboxes extends JFormField
{

    protected $type = 'ArticlesCheckboxes';

    protected function getInput()
    {

        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select(array($db->quoteName('id'), $db->quoteName('title')));
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

        $result = '';

        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            $result .= '<label>' . $row->title . '</label><input type="checkbox" name="articles[]"  value="' . $row->id . '"/>';
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

4. I presume this is preliminary SQL as right now this will pull back **every article** in the website, published or not, expired and trashed even. You may want to consider using the `com_content` model for articles `ContentModelArticles` which will give you all the advantages of using a `JModelList` object, like filtering, and `getItems()` which returns a list of articles you can use.

Comment: So much information on one place :). This really explains a lot (you explained more detailed then most "tutorials" I could find). I am new to Joomla (I was forced to create template and few modules, and before Joomla I worked CodeIgniter, Laravel and OOP PHP) - if you know about tutorials (video or books) which are good as answer and you could point me to them, that would be great :). Thank you a lot for this answer :)

Comment: The only thing I'd suggest is extending JFormFieldCheckboxes since that will set up lots of things for you including validation etc.